# keras.layers.Input: AttributeError: 'OpDefLibrary' object has no attribute '_apply_op_helper'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

I use spider (python 3.6) on Mac.

I try to use keras to create some input, and I typed in the following code:

```
from keras.layers import Input
input_target = Input(shape=(1,))
```

Then I got the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-33-804299fafc3c>", line 1, in <module>
  input_target = Input(shape=(1,))

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1457, in Input
  input_tensor=tensor)

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1366, in __init__
  name=self.name)

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 508, in placeholder
  x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
  # Matrix with two batch dimensions.

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
  the images. Must be: `[1, stride_rows, stride_cols, 1]`.

File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 327, in apply_op
  output_structure, is_stateful, op = self._apply_op_helper(

AttributeError: 'OpDefLibrary' object has no attribute '_apply_op_helper'
```

I looked at the topology.py file where it gives an error:

```
if not batch_shape and tensor is None:
    assert shape is not None, ('Please provide to Input either a `shape`'
                               ' or a `batch_shape` argument. Note that '
                               '`shape` does not include the batch '
                               'dimension.')
if shape is not None and not batch_shape:
    batch_shape = (None,) + tuple(shape)
if not dtype:
    dtype = K.floatx()
input_layer = InputLayer(batch_input_shape=batch_shape,
                         name=name, dtype=dtype,
                         sparse=sparse,
                         input_tensor=tensor)
```

I don't know what might cause the problem. Anything to do with the way how keras and its backend tensorflow define shape? I installed keras and tensorflow from Conda, and then installed tensorflow from Conda. It should be a pretty simple code using keras, and I don't understand why it cannot run.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uninstall (use conda remove keras/tensorflow) and just re-install keras from conda-forge. I then restarted the spider. It seems working now.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem with environment: `Python 3.6`, `tensorflow 1.13.1`, `Spyder 3.3.4`.

I solved this problem by

1. **installing `tensorflow-eigen` with `anaconda`** (still not working while not restarted Spyder),
2. then **restarted `Spyder`**.